# Having issues removing UIViews from a UIScrollView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, oop

I'm trying to make code that will add players to a view based on objects but, I'm having some issues.

Right now currently if I run the initView method with 4 confirmed working Player objects in playerList, only 3 UIViews will appear in my scrollview, then when I click the clear players button, only the last (3rd) UIView will be removed.

A side note, none of my custom buttons appear in the UIViews either, I have an image that they should load with, but its not working.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
- (void)clearPlayers {
    for (Player* i in self.playerList) {
        [i.viewPane removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [self.playerList removeAllObjects];
}

- (void)initView {
    int Loc = 0;
    int Count = 1;
    int margin = 5;
    int height = 100;
    for (Player *p in playerList) {
        UIView *playerView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, Loc, 320.0, height)];
        p.viewPane = playerView;
        [playerView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [scrollView addSubview:playerView];
        UIButton *plus = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(200, 10, (height - 5), (height - 5))];
        UIImage *buttonImage =[[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Metal_Plus_Up_2.png"];
        [plus setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [p.viewPane addSubview:plus];

        [plus release];
        [playerView release];
        Loc = Loc + (height + margin);
        Count = Count + 1;
    }
    [scrollView setContentSize:CGSizeMake(320.0, (height * Count) + (margin * Count))];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Question: have you verified that the UIImage returned from *initWithContentsOfFile* is not nil?  You might need the full path instead of just the filename

As far as the wackiness with the UIViews not getting removed goes, everything you've posted looks fine as far as I can see.  The only thing I can think of is that maybe you don't have *retain* specified as an attribute for your *viewPane* property...

Comment: after i posted i found out that it was because i wasnt loading from the bundle, i fixed that then i found out that i was running initview once for each object in another method, when i removed that it fixed it. but of course SO doesnt let you answer your own question for like a day unless your rep is high.